# C++ CLI openCV Stitching Access Violation

Tags: c#, opencv, c++-cli

i am trying for a while now to do some stitching in openCV (2.4.6 - now 2.4.8) using a C++ dll
called from C#.
Everything seems fine until the stitching starts:

```
int _imageCount;
Mat _images[40];

void OpenCvInterop::AddImage(cli::array<cli::array<unsigned char>^>^ pCBuf, cli::array<int>^ pArrCounters)
{
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(false);

    std::vector<Mat>  imgs;
    std::vector<IplImage*>  imgsRead;

    // assuming just 2 imgs for now
    for( int i = 0; i<2; i++ )
    {
        //size of the img
        int arrCount = pArrCounters[i];

        //copy the arr to vector
        array<unsigned char>^ myArr = pCBuf[i];
        std::vector<char> msg(arrCount, '\0');
        for(int xx = 0;xx<arrCount;xx++)
        {
            msg[xx] = (char)myArr[xx];
        }

        //writing the vector back to file - success
        //std::ofstream outfile ("new.jpg",std::ofstream::binary);
        //outfile.write ((const char*)&msg[0], msg.size());

        //clone imgs
        cv::Mat imgMat = Mat(cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)cv::imdecode(Mat(msg), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED).clone()));
        cv::Mat image = Mat(cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)imgMat.clone()));

        //apply filter - success
        cv::GaussianBlur(imgMat, image, cv::Size(0, 0), 3);
        cv::addWeighted(imgMat, 1.5, image, -0.5, 0, image);

        //copy again - success
        IplImage* writeImage = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)image);
        //saving the image - success
        cvSaveImage("readfirst.jpg", writeImage);

        //copy again - success
        Mat(writeImage).copyTo(_images[i]);
        cvReleaseImage(&writeImage);

        //add to array
        imgs.push_back(_images[i].clone());
        _imageCount += 1;
    }

    Mat pano1;
    //array imgs is filled properly
    //gives access violation here:
    stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano1);
```

If i read the images using imread all is fine.
imshow also displays the images well - even with the sharping filter applyed.
Thanks in advance,
Tino

Comment: please follow this procedure and edit your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6decc55h.aspx

Comment: the av is in the opencv_core248 lib stating that there is an access to memory 0x00000000

Comment: get rid of that iplimages, for heaven's sake ! *never* mix c++ with that dreaded c-api

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution by myself:

I created the solution again in a new folder, builded opencv new and it worked.